# Is there a way to prevent this weird project and solution generation done by Unity when using asmdef files?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity and its automatic generation of project files are great, HOWEVER, when using `asmdef` files, things get really weird. Most of the time it is normal, but it can get really screwed up seemingly at random times. (VS will ask me if I want to reload the solution before it happens) These screw-ups just don't contain ANY scripts what-so-ever and just contain the `asmdef` files alongside what appears to be theme files for the Unity Editor. I can fix the bad `csproj/sln` generation by closing Unity and deleting all the `csproj` and `sln` files and reloading everything. I'm just looking for what could be causing it and what I could do to prevent it. (Sorry for the paragraph :D)

**Example of normal generation:**

[image: Normal Generation]

**Example of weird generation:**

[image: Weird Generation]

**Other info:**

- Unity 2018.1.0b8
- Windows 10 Creators Update
- Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem. Solved by updating Visual Studio to latest version. Try to check updates inside VS (flag icon on top right corner)

Comment: I have to say: was pretty skeptical about this answer, but it sure helped me to resolve my issue. Thank you, Obikson